# Encrypt in CryptoJS (Angular) and do the same in Crypto (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, encryption, cryptojs

I am having trouble encrypting a password in Angular vs NodeJS.

For example, the password I'm  using is: **test**

In Angular I am using CryptoJS:

```
encryptUsingAES256(password) {
      let _key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("elservidordelgatotuerto88");
      let _iv =  CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("elservidordelgatotuerto88");
      let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        password, _key, {
          iv: _iv,
          format: CryptoJS.format.Hex,
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
          padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }).toString();
      return encrypted;
}
```

The value I get from this function is: **b75d0db663be668a24498aaa460f8896**

Now, I also want to encrypt the same value in NodeJS using Crypto:

```
public encrypt(text) {
        try {
            var cipher = createCipher("aes-256-ctr", "elservidordelgatotuerto88");
            var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
            crypted += cipher.final('hex');
            return crypted;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error( 'couldn\'t encrypt text' );
        }
}
```

And the value I get is different: **067e0c77**

I want to obtain in Angular the same result that NodeJS gives me (**067e0c77**).

What could be the fixes that I should make in Angular?

Thank you!!

Comment: Why can't you use the same library and the same code on both?

Comment: Because the Crypto library isn't compatible with Angular 7 versions upwards

Comment: What about the other way around? Use your Angular code in Node? I have a feeling you're not setting up the cipher exactly the same way on both ends.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about doing the same thing in Node, but I can't edit the code there.

Comment: I don't see a call to `createCipheriv` in the second sample, so it's likely you're not initializing that consistently. You're only setting the password. It's also a problem because your IV is not a valid IV. That should be exactly 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

With a few changes we can make the output of the Crypto.js and Node crypto encryption identical.

We need to remove the padding in Crypto.js and also ensure that the key and iv are exactly the same.

The code will look like so:

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const crypto = require("crypto");

function encryptUsingAES256(password, key, iv) {
    let _key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    let _iv =  CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
    let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    password, _key, {
        iv: _iv,
        format: CryptoJS.format.Hex,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
    }).toString();
    return encrypted;
}

function encryptUsingNodeCrypto(text, key, iv) {
    try {
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-ctr", key, iv);
        let crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
        crypted += cipher.final('hex');
        return crypted;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("encryptUsingNodeCrypto: An error occurred: ", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

const originalText = "test";
const key = "elservidordelgatelservidordelgat";
const iv = "elservidordelgat";

const encryptedTextCryptoJs = encryptUsingAES256(originalText, key, iv);
console.log(`Crypto.js: "${originalText}" was encrypted to "${encryptedTextCryptoJs}"`);

const encryptedTextNodeJs = encryptUsingNodeCrypto(originalText, key, iv);
console.log(`Node.js: "${originalText}" was encrypted to "${encryptedTextNodeJs}"`);
```

I'm getting identical results for the same input.